# Django custom validator with multiple inputs

Tags: python, django

Im trying to create a custom validator that must be able to validate different conditions given a `type`

```
def validator(value, type, param):

    match type:
        case 'regex_validator':
            if not re.search(param, value):
                raise ValidationError()
        case 'max_length':
            if value > param:
                raise ValidationError()
```

and my question is: How can I pass the function the form value? The examples I have seen don't implicitly pass the value to the validator.

I want to do declare the the form fiel like this:

```
forms.CharField(validators=[validator(value, x['type'], x['param'] for x in field_validators])
```

Comment: What is your **field_validators** ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru it's a list of dicts that have a `type` (type of validator thta can be 'regex_validator' or `max_length` and a `param` (expected value that in case of 'regex_validator' is a regex string and in case 'max_length' will be a integer.

Answer (score 0):

Django does not allow to make a multi fields validation with field validators. You have to do your validation in the clean_FIELDNAME function form.

```
class FormExample():
    field = forms.CharField()

    def clean_field(self, data):
        if XXX:
            validator = RegexValidator()
        elif YYYY:
            validator = MaxLengthValidator()

        validator(data)
```

Or you can create a custom field with overrided validate function for making your custom choice of validator (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning)